# почему в файле сохраняется только последняя строка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    if '.194.100' in output:
        # with open('DHCP.txt', 'w') as file:
        #     file.write(output)
        for line in ip_mac_lines:
            if '0100' not in line:
                ok = line.split()
                f = operator.itemgetter(1)
                okk = str(f(ok))
                okk = okk.replace("'", "")
                okk = re.sub(r'[\(\)]', '', str(okk))
                okk = okk.replace(".", "")
                if '01' in okk:
                    okk = okk[2:]
                    #print(okk)
                    mac = ':'.join(okk[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(okk), 2))
                    #send_email(mac)
                    with open('DHCP010101.txt', 'w') as file:
                        file.write(mac)
                    if '00:23' in mac:
                        print(mac)
```

Comment: Ну потому что вы каждый раз файл заново целиком переписываете внутри цикла. Либо открывайте файл до цикла. Либо поменяйте режим открытия файла на `a` - `append`.

Comment: теперь пишет все в файле после того на "a" заменил, но теперь пишет все подряд без пробелов и без \n

Comment: Ну добавьте их туда: `file.write(mac + '\n')`

Comment: #send_email(mac) - это функция должна выполняет задачу  после того как все мак адреса соберутся вместе, тогда отправить их на почту. Когда включаю вызываю ее она каждый мак по отдельности на почту шлет, а не за один раз. Как это исправить вы не знаете?

Comment: Ну опять же перенесите её на после окончания цикла. Но нужно будет либо собрать адреса в список, либо пусть она читает из того файла их

Comment: после того как добавил это file.write(mac + '\n'), теперь в файле сначала на верху все подряд пишет, а ниже использую \n

Answer (score 1):

Вообще в комментариях уже сказали, что вы ошиблись в методе открытия файла (не `w`, a `a`).
Но если вы хотите, чтобы при каждом запуске файл очищался, то есть 2 варианта:

1. Собственно, намеренно выделить строку для очищения файла:

```
with open('DHCP010101.txt', 'w'): pass

if '.194.100' in output: 
# ваш остальной код, в котором файл открывается `open('DHCP010101.txt', 'a')`
# вот так
with open('DHCP010101.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(mac)
```

2. Или так:

```
file = open('DHCP010101.txt', 'w')
if '.194.100' in output: 
# ваш остальной код без открытий файла. 
# вот так
file.write(mac)

file.close() # не забудьте эту строку цикла
```